# Can I online redefnition a table without specifying the column?

Tags: oracle

I have a table with many columns (more then 100 columns) which I want to online REDEFINITION. If I execute it as below

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('scott',
   'TABLE_ROWDEPENDENCY','TABLE_ROWDEPENDENCY1',
             dbms_redefinition.cons_use_pk);
END;
/
```

I get error ora-42106: Shape of interim table does not match specified column mapping.

its fixed in this way however I have to include all the 100 columns in order for all the data to be inserted:

```
BEGIN
      DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('scott',
       'TABLE_ROWDEPENDENCY','TABLE_ROWDEPENDENCY1','tablename tablename , id id , code code' ,
                 dbms_redefinition.cons_use_pk);
    END;
    /
```

Edit1 :

after some testing I noticed removing the  dbms_redefinition.cons_use_pk would work:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('scott',
   'TABLE_ROWDEPENDENCY','TABLE_ROWDEPENDENCY1');
END;
/
```

But as per the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/tables007.htm#i1006801) removing it is still will be used.

> Package constants are provided for specifying the redefinition method.
> DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_PK is used to indicate that the
> redefinition should be done using primary keys or pseudo-primary keys.
> DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID is use to indicate that the
> redefinition should be done using rowids. If this argument is omitted,
> the default method of redefinition (CONS_USE_PK) is assumed.

Comment: If you want a subset of the columns, use the parameter `col_mapping`. The use of cons_use_pk simply requires a primary key on the source table. Those two has little to do with each other. See the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_REDEFINITION.html#GUID-09FE5412-519C-412F-B1E0-77F75B1E8CA7

Comment: @oisene why adding  cons_use_pk i get error but removing it I dont face error ?

Comment: From your last code snippet it looked like you also removed the col_mapping parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in package calls are ordered so you can't just list the parameters you want to use in any order.  Looking at START_REDEF_TABLE you'll see:

```
PROCEDURE START_REDEF_TABLE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 UNAME                          VARCHAR2                IN
 ORIG_TABLE                     VARCHAR2                IN
 INT_TABLE                      VARCHAR2                IN
 COL_MAPPING                    VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 OPTIONS_FLAG                   BINARY_INTEGER          IN     DEFAULT
 ORDERBY_COLS                   VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 PART_NAME                      VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 CONTINUE_AFTER_ERRORS          BOOLEAN                 IN     DEFAULT
 COPY_VPD_OPT                   BINARY_INTEGER          IN     DEFAULT
 REFRESH_DEP_MVIEWS             VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 ENABLE_ROLLBACK                BOOLEAN                 IN     DEFAULT
```

which means you would need to specify first

'SCOTT'
'TABLE1'
'TABLE2'

and THEN the col mapping and THEN the options flag.

For this reason, its a good practice to use the ***named*** parameter syntax, ie

```
DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE
(uname=>'SCOTT',
 orig_table=>'TABLE1',
 int_table=>'TABLE2',
 ...
 ...
```

By naming the parameters , the order is no longer important because we explicitly associating the parameters with their values, so you could just as easily do

```
DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE
(int_table=>'TABLE2',
 orig_table=>'TABLE1',
 uname=>'SCOTT'
 ...
 ...
```

and so forth.  It also makes it easier for the next person who comes along to maintain your code.